# Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure

Tags: c++, build, arm

So, I am trying to compile a Homebrew App for CFW Nintendo 3DS. I am doing it on Linux Mint 18.2. The compiler fails to compile some required dependencies.

Here is the code from the compiler:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

mkdir -p build

# Install libarchive and libmpg123 for host
apt-get update
apt-get -y install libarchive-dev libmpg123-dev

# Install libarchive for 3ds
git clone https://github.com/Cruel/3ds_portlibs.git
cd 3ds_portlibs
make zlib
make install-zlib
make libarchive
make install

# Install libmpg123 for 3ds
wget -O libmpg123-dev.tar.gz  https://notabug.org/attachments/216a6d61-f167-4f65-84dc-fa98c2247fc1
tar -xaf libmpg123-dev.tar.gz -C $DEVKITPRO/portlibs/3ds

cd ../build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_EMULATOR=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=ON ..
make -j4
```

Here is the output error that I get:

```
+ mkdir -p build
+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:12 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya InRelease
Hit:13 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya Release
Hit:15 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 204 kB in 5s (38.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
+ apt-get -y install libarchive-dev libmpg123-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libmpg123-dev is already the newest version (1.22.4-1).
libarchive-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-2~ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 100 not upgraded.
+ git clone https://github.com/Cruel/3ds_portlibs.git
Cloning into '3ds_portlibs'...
+ cd 3ds_portlibs
+ CFLAGS=-m64
+ make zlib
wget -O zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz "http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz"
--2017-08-02 08:47:03--  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
Resolving prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Connecting to prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz [following]
--2017-08-02 08:47:03--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz [following]
--2017-08-02 08:47:04--  https://versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
Resolving versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net (versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net)... 104.238.205.251
Connecting to versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net (versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net)|104.238.205.251|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 571091 (558K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz’

2017-08-02 08:47:04 (1.95 MB/s) - ‘zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz’ saved [571091/571091]

Using ar
Checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc...
Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
** ./configure aborting.
Makefile:195: recipe for target 'zlib' failed
make: *** [zlib] Error 1
```

I also noticed if I remove the lines about zlib, I get a different error:

```
+ export CPP3DS=/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/cpp3ds
+ for dev in ''\''arc13'\'''
+ cd /home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop
+ for dx in '"3ds_portlibs"' '"build"'
+ '[' -d 3ds_portlibs ']'
+ rm -r 3ds_portlibs
+ for dx in '"3ds_portlibs"' '"build"'
+ '[' -d build ']'
+ rm -r build
+ mkdir -p build
+ export CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
+ CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
+ export CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++
+ CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++
+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Ign:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya Release
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease
Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
+ apt-get -y install libarchive-dev libmpg123-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libmpg123-dev is already the newest version (1.22.4-1).
libarchive-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-2~ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
+ git clone https://github.com/Cruel/3ds_portlibs.git
Cloning into '3ds_portlibs'...
+ cd 3ds_portlibs
+ make CC=DEVKITPRO
Please choose one of the following targets:
  freetype (requires zlib to be installed)
  libexif
  libjpeg-turbo
  libpng (requires zlib to be installed)
  sqlite
  zlib
  mxml
  expat
  libxml2
  jansson
  physfs (requires zlib to be installed)
  libmad
  libogg
  libvorbis (requires libogg to be installed)
  giflib
  libconfig
  bzip2
  xz
  libarchive
  nettle
  wslay
+ make libarchive
wget -O libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz "http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz"
--2017-08-02 16:36:34--  http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz
Resolving www.libarchive.org (www.libarchive.org)... 2600:9000:2025:5a00:16:e6b0:f440:93a1, 2600:9000:2025:fe00:16:e6b0:f440:93a1, 2600:9000:2025:2600:16:e6b0:f440:93a1, ...
Connecting to www.libarchive.org (www.libarchive.org)|2600:9000:2025:5a00:16:e6b0:f440:93a1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4527540 (4.3M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz’

2017-08-02 16:36:40 (54.6 MB/s) - ‘libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz’ saved [4527540/4527540]

patching file libarchive/archive_ppmd7.c
patching file libarchive/archive_read_disk_posix.c
patching file libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c
patching file libarchive/archive_write_set_format_iso9660.c
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-none-eabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-none-eabi
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... arm-none-eabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/3ds_portlibs/libarchive-3.1.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Makefile:274: recipe for target 'libarchive' failed
make: *** [libarchive] Error 77
```

Judging from the error, it seems that I'm compiling an ARM application on a 64-bit system and it fails due to that. However, I need to compile the source code in ARM since it's supposed to be installed on a Nintendo 3DS. How can I fix this error in order to compile the application?

Edit: I tried setting up the compiler for root and got this error:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc" is not able
  to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_ef3eb/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  Linking C executable cmTC_ef3eb

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/link.txt
  --verbose=1

  /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_ef3eb -rdynamic

  arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'

  CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef3eb.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_ef3eb'
  failed

  make[1]: *** [cmTC_ef3eb] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_ef3eb/fast' failed

  make: *** [cmTC_ef3eb/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I am also getting this error:

```
-- strip: /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/arm-none-eabi-strip - found
-- 3dslink: /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/3dslink - found
-- Looking for Picasso...
-- Picasso: /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM/bin/picasso - found
-- Looking for nihstro...
-- nihstro - not found
CMake Error at /home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/cpp3ds/cmake/template_emu/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/eddy/Documents/FreeShop/arc13/freeshop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867271/zlib-harsh-compiler-warnings-and-configure-test), it looks like it's failing as it can't find a valid compiler.

You'll need to download a cross compiler in order to compile code for one architecture on a different one. You can follow the steps in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250696/cross-compile-for-arm) question to get an ARM compiler, and then the `./configure` script may work on its own (it looks like it's looking for a cross compiler), or you can use eg.:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

...before running `./configure` to set the compilers for the build system (assuming it obeys the `CC` convention).

If this doesn't work, you may need specific DS cross-compilers, rather than just generic ARM ones. It might be worth looking at [this site](https://wiki.gbatemp.net/wiki/3DS_Homebrew_Development) if you haven't already, to see if their `devkitARM` provides the cross compiler you need.

**Edit**: If you look carefully at your new output, you'll see `make CC=DEVKITPRO`. This is calling `make` directly with `DEVKITPRO` set as the compiler, overriding any attempts to change the compiler beforehand.

You should make sure the `DEVKITPRO` binary is accessible from your `PATH` - open a terminal and type DEVKITPRO and see if you can execute it, or if it's not found. If it's not found, check over the instructions on the `devkitARM` page referenced above to make sure you've installed it as they expected, in particular the line in the Linux installation instructions saying `echo "export DEVKITPRO=/opt/devkitPro" >> ~/.bashrc`.

**Edit Edit**: There's a list of libraries and toolkits [here](https://wiki.gbatemp.net/wiki/List_of_3DS_development_tools#Libraries_and_tools). Look on your project's installation page to find any dependencies, and track them down and install them as well.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed the application says this on it's source code page:
"for the moment, (app) must be compiled with devkitARM r46/libctru 1.2.1/citro3D 1.2.0"

Comment: Even though I installed devkitARM, it seems that it still uses the same compiler instead of devkitARM.

Comment: @EduardoPerez Have you tried using the `CC=` trick? If you tried with the above and it didn't work, try with `CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc` and the appropriate for `CXX`, as that's what your output implies it's looking for.

Comment: I also noticed if I remove the 2 lines involving zlib, I get a different error. I'll update the question to reflect that. Would it help if I were to link to the application's source code?

Comment: I think I figured it out. It seems that I had it setup for my user, but I was running the script as root.

Comment: It seems that it can't find nihstro

Comment: @EduardoPerez This [nihstro](https://wiki.gbatemp.net/wiki/Nihstro)? The step after the installation instructions for devKitARM is one saying you should install libraries. See minor edit to post.

Comment: @EduardoPerez: your comment helped me fix this issue. I had the compiler setup for user, but not for root apparently. I would advice anyone with the same issue to check this option before trying anything else!